# RemoteAction not returning object variables

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using the standard remoteaction found in the tutorial to bring an object from the controller to JS using remoteAction however, when i return the object it is not giving me access to object variables. Only Id returns a value. Does @RemoteAction Send objects back with variables?

```
@RemoteAction
    global static Template__c getTemplateDetails(String TemplateName)
    {
        Template__c template;
        template = [SELECT CalculationMethod__c, CalculationType__c, Compounding__c, PaymentFrequency__c, CalculationDay__c FROM Template__c WHERE Name = :TemplateName];
        return template;
    }
```

After i return the template the result can only access .id

```
 Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
    '{!$RemoteAction.loanController.getTemplateDetails}',
      templateName, 
      function(result, event){
         if (event.status) {
            alert(result.Name); //is undefined
            alert(result.PaymentFrequency__c) //is undefined
             alert(result.id) //is defined
            $('[id$=PaymentFrequency]').val(result.PaymentFrequency__c);  
            } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
            } else {
            }
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
```

But Returns on String types work.

Comment: Name is empty because you are not querying it.

Comment: Fair enough, but if i do a return type that isn't String it breaks on the VF Page

Comment: This should work, documentation e.g. here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm  Maybe the binding to the page doesn't work ok? Also there's an ; missing after the paymentFrequency alter but I'm not 100% sure if that's a problem in Javascript..

Comment: I typed those lines there to demonstrate what wasn't and was working, forgot to put the semi colons. I currently have the exact same thing as that link. But returning custom objects give me a undefined error

Comment: Check you have the casing of the field names exactly right (in your above example you have id not Id). Can you also confirm that the fields do not have a namespace prefix?

Comment: In the back end, do they have values? Id is having a value obviously, other fields may have null values which may gives undefined in JavaScript

Comment: Yeah they have it, I got it working. It refused to accept custom objects so i made an string array. Then i tried to bring in a numeric string it is now undefined. Back to square 1

Comment: Turns out there is a limit in the amount of items you can send in a list from @RemoteAction to VF Page

Comment: Hi James. I would be interested in where you find that limit. Is it documented by SF somewhere?

Comment: No idea but i am testing it myself and when i get to a string array in which it is beyond 4. it doesn't send the elements beyond [3]. For eg x[0]=1, x[1]=2 ..... x[4]= undef. I haven't seen anything documented so it could be a bug in their system. Because i swapped content arrays around and it worked but the 4th index was undef. My List itself was dynamic and i was using the list.add method.

Answer (score 4):

While apex is case-insensitive generally javascript *is* case sensitive. It's quite likley that the PaymentFrequency__c field's name is not defined in that case.

Generally it's helpful to use something like console.log() on the client side which shows the full state of the result object to find out exactly what the data looks like when you have issues.